# How do I get rid of an empty string with using while loop? (python)

Tags: python, string, list, while-loop

```
list1 = ["apple", "pear", "", "strawberry", "orange", "grapes", "", "watermelon"]
list2 = []
x = 0
while x < len(list1):
    if len(list1[x]) > 0:
        list2.append(list1[x])
print(list2)
```

I tried to run this code, but it seems that it doesn't work. How should I revise this code by not using list comprehension or other methods?

Comment: Edit the question to explain "doesn't work", what happens, what should happen?

Comment: hmm, this seems to be an infinite loop. I'd suggest breaking out of the while loop or incrementing `x` for example.

Comment: Adding `x += 1` at the end of the loop seems to give the correct output for me

Comment: @Jab because OP say : `How should I revise this code by not using list comprehension or other methods?`

Comment: @user1740577 Honestly I hadn't seen the "not" in that sentence either. Need more caffeine.

Comment: @Selcuk :::))))

Answer (score 5):

Update: Just noticed that you do **not** want to use a different method, so this answer is for future visitors only.

You can implement the same functionality in a single line:

```
list2 = list(filter(None, list1))
```

Note that this will also remove elements that are equal to `0`, `False`, or `None`. A closer implementation could be with a list comprehension:

```
list2 = [i for i in list1 if i != ""]
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: because you say *`(How should I revise this code by not using list comprehension or other methods?)`* I send this answer otherwise other answers are better for the future.

You need to increase the index, here in your code `x+=1` like below:

```
list1 = ["apple", "pear", "", "strawberry", "orange", "grapes", "", "watermelon"]
list2 = []
x = 0
while x < len(list1):
    if len(list1[x]) > 0:
        list2.append(list1[x])
    x += 1
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'orange', 'grapes', 'watermelon']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is your desired output:

```
['apple', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'orange', 'grapes', 'watermelon']
```

Here's a way without using builtins or list comprehensions:

```py
list1 = ["apple", "pear", "", "strawberry", "orange", "grapes", "", "watermelon"]

list2 = []
for x in list1:
    x and list2.append(x)
```

Assuming are allowed to use builtins such as `filter`:

```py
list1 = ["apple", "pear", "", "strawberry", "orange", "grapes", "", "watermelon"]
list2 = list(filter(None, list1))
```